# Pascal, Ordinal error

Tags: pascal, freepascal, ordinal

I need to run a loop for 10 billion times and failing to run it, please help me get this done. I am getting ordinal error.

```
program kittu;
    var i:qword;
        j:qword;
        k:qword;
begin
    i:= 10000000000;
    k:= 0;
    for j:=1 to i do
        begin
            k:=k+1;
        end;
    writeln(k);
    readln();
end.
```

Comment: What does "failing to run it" mean? We can't see your computer.

Comment: It Says Ordinal Expression Expected at j:=1 on j

Answer (score 4):

From the FreePascal docs for this error message.

> Error: Ordinal expression expected The expression must be of ordinal
>   type, i.e., maximum a Longint. This happens, for instance, when you
>   specify a second argument to Inc or Dec that doesn’t evaluate to an
>   ordinal value.

Your variable K is defined as qword, which is a 64-bit length. LongInt is 32 bit.

Comment: And Longints (32 bit) can't go up to 10 billion. Their limit is around 2 billion. So he'll have to nest loops.

Answer (score -2):

The `for` statement is platform dependent.

Observation: qword is not supported to be used as a counter variable on 32-bit platform.

But seems no documentary support to tell which set of datatypes are supported to be used as counter variables.

Tried in both 32-bit and 64-bit platforms:

32-bit:
declaration of variable `j` could be changed to datatype `dword` to get it successfully compiled.
It is also required to compile with `release` mode to prevent getting an error due to overflow.

Compiler: Free Pascal IDE for Win32 for i386
Target CPU: i386
Version 1.0.12 2017/02/13
Compiler Version: 3.0.2
Environment: Win10

**edit:**
Successfully compiled with i386 free pascal **with x86_64 cross compiler**
on 64-bit Win10 **(edit2: in the left hand side's command line)**
 
[[Image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/US3c7.png)
**Guess**: the counter in `for` statement might be optimized with using registers. Under i386 configuration, qword is too large for a 32-bit register.

64-bit:
[[Image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWYKJ.png)

But it seems to work fine in 64-bit platform.

Compiler: Free Pascal Compiler version 3.0.2 [2017/03/18] for x86_64
Environment: Mac OSX 10.11.6

Comment: Your first image shows that it did not successfully compile.

Comment: The first image shows that it compiles in command line with ppcrossx64 in the left hand side.

Comment: Gotcha. I hadn't paid attention to the background. Very interesting what you found.